# ReplaceAll and derivatives

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I have the following coming from a computation,
$$h_1 (u,v,w) = \frac{1}{v}\partial_v g(u,v,w)$$
and in *Mathematica* I have different quantities in terms of $h_1$ and its derivatives like $\partial_uh_1$, etc.
My problem is to implement the substitution (and analogous ones) in the expressions involving derivatives.
Concretely I want to make a rule `subst =  h1 -> 1/v D[g[u, v, w], v]` etc. but, as I was expecting when I try to evaluate `D[h1[u, v, w], u] /. subst` I get $h_1^{\{0,1,0\}}(u,v,w)$.

Any suggestion?

**Reformatting code** (thanks to MarcoB)
Substitution rules are the following,

```
rules={h1[u, v, w] -> (1/v)*D[g[u, v, w], v], h2[u, v, w] -> (1/w)*D[g[u, v, w], w]}
```

then I would like to use the following

```
ω[1] = reWrite[d[h1] + I*d[φ[1]] - D[h1[u, v, w], u]*(d[u] + I*u*d[φ[3]])]; 
ω[2] = reWrite[d[h2] + I*d[φ[2]] - D[h2[u, v, w], u]*(d[u] + I*u*d[φ[3]])];
```

and

```
reWrite[Sum[A[i]*ω[i]*ωb[i], {i, 1, 2}] + A[0]*(ω[1]*ωb[2] + ωb[1]*ω[2])] /. rules
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks to be the default way of expressing derivatives; e.g. `Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]` for the partial derivative of `f[x, y]` with respect to `x`. Why would this be not useful for you?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the actual *Mathematica* form of those expressions, rather than Latex. See here as well: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: The problem is the pattern matching. Your rules replace the pattern `h1[u, v, w]`, but what actually appears in your expression are derivatives of `h1` which look like, for instance, `Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][u, v, w]`. To make it work, see for instance [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40189/replace-rule-with-function-derivatives-dont-evaluate) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions).

Comment: For instance, try this replacement `Rule` instead: `h1 -> (1/#2 Derivative[0, 1, 0][g][#1, #2, #3] &)`.

Comment: Code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/replacement-of-terms-pattern-matching-involving-products-of-derivatives-of-a-fun) might apply.